# Как вручную подключить библиотеку Intervention/image в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Поскольку через composer require в РФ теперь это библиотеку не загрузить
возникает ошибка

```
$ composer require intervention/image

Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
    Using version ^2.7 for intervention/image
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Running composer update intervention/image
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

решил скачать ее с Github https://github.com/Intervention/image

### composer.json пакета

в корне нашел composer.json c таким содержимым

```
{
    "name": "intervention/image",
    "description": "Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration",
    "homepage": "http://image.intervention.io/",
    "keywords": ["image", "gd", "imagick", "laravel", "watermark", "thumbnail"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Oliver Vogel",
            "email": "oliver@intervention.io",
            "homepage": "https://intervention.io/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "~1.1 || ^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8 || ^5.7 || ^7.5.15",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9.2"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-gd": "to use GD library based image processing.",
        "ext-imagick": "to use Imagick based image processing.",
        "intervention/imagecache": "Caching extension for the Intervention Image library"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Intervention\\Image\\": "src/Intervention/Image"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        },
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Intervention\\Image\\ImageServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Image": "Intervention\\Image\\Facades\\Image"
            }
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

саму библиотеку положил по пути `app/Libs/Intervension`

### composer.json в корне проекта

в файле composer.json в корне проекта прописал пути по аналогии

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/System/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Intervention\\Image\\": "app/Libs/Intervension/src/Intervention/Image"
    }
},
```

...

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [],
        "providers": [
            "Intervention\\Image\\ImageServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Image": "Intervention\\Image\\Facades\\Image"
        }
    }
},
```

### Конфиг app.php

в конфиге `config/app.php` так же прописал сервис-провайдеры

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
...
]
```

...

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
])->toArray(),
```

при попытке обратиться к классу начать работу с картинкой

```
$image = \Image::make($uri);
```

Получаю ошибку

> Class "Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider" not found

Comment: "Поскольку через composer require в РФ теперь это библиотеку не загрузить" --- почему?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дополнил вопрос

Comment: И это совсем не значит что теперь в РФ это нельзя загрузить. Это значит что в проекте твоем какие-то конфликты версий. И после сообщения "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." должен идти список проблем.

Comment: Нет. Ты ошибся. То, что там надпись - ничего не значит.... Она просто говорит что композер стэнд виз укрэйн..............твоя проблема в том что "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Comment: спасибо, понял
по совпадению вторая библиотека с этим хештегом не ставится..
возможно он теперь всегда показывается, буду разбираться

Comment: хэштег ещё минимум с марта висит в композере............но советую библиотеки ставить которые версией  **до 24 февраля**